# Float images inside card div bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I use card div.
The card has display flex and I can't float images, maybe because the card wants just one image.
How Can I float images inside?[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: use flex-row class with the div to get float effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `.card-body` displayed as a wrapped flexbox, and set its `justify-content` to `flex-start` (which is default). There are [Bootstrap built-in classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/) you can use as well.

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/cb9n652j/8/